# Griddle v1 onRowClick not firing

Tags: reactjs, griddle

Was tasked to upgrade from Griddle v0.7 to Griddle v1.1. But I can't seeme to get onRowClick to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Griddle from 'griddle-react';

export default class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = [...something];

    return <Griddle
      data={data} 
      onRowClick={() => console.log("row clicked")} /> 
  }
}
```

If I look through the issues on github or other examples, this should work just fine.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out? I'm currently experiencing the same issue (upgrading from 0.7 to 1.5), and can't seem to find anyway to get `onClick` to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Griddle v1 way to solve this would be to define a `RowEnhancer` to provide an `onClick`, like [this example](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/blob/42bc9aea172e3b272481eb15b0f4dc6544ab9872/stories/index.tsx#L154-L162):

```
  <Griddle
    components={{
      RowEnhancer: OriginalComponent =>
        props => (
          <OriginalComponent
            {...props}
            onClick={() => console.log(`Click Row ${props.griddleKey}`)}
            />
        ),
    }}
    ...
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no onRowClick as v1 (and still none as of v1.3.1).
You need to build a custom row component or cell if you want to add an action.